# Can a generic method assign values to properties on an object with a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I threw together a quick utility to create test data quickly.  Basically, I wanted to be able to say, "give me some data with the numeric properties populated."

So, something like this:

```js
const testData = TestUtils.getStringFields<User>(['username', 'password'], 1118);
/*
  testData = {
    username: 'username - 1118',
    password: 'password - 1118',
  }
*/
```

It works fine, but some of the type information appears to get lost in the implementation:

```js
type TypedFields<T, TField> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TField ? K : never }[keyof T];

type NumericFields<T> = TypedFields<T, number>;
type NumericPartial<T> = Partial<Pick<T, NumericFields<T>>>;

type StringFields<T> = TypedFields<T, string>;
type StringPartial<T> = Partial<Pick<T, StringFields<T>>>;

export class TestUtils {
  public static *numberSequence(initialValue = 0): Generator<number, number> {
    let i = initialValue - 1;
    while(true) { yield ++i; }
  }

  public static getNumericFields<T>(fields: NumericFields<T>[], initialValue = -1): NumericPartial<T> {
    const response: NumericPartial<T> = {};
    const sequence = this.numberSequence(initialValue);

    fields.forEach(field => {
      // this works
      response[field] = sequence.next().value as unknown as T[NumericFields<T>];

      // this gives me a complier error Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never; }[keyof T]] | undefined'.ts(2322)
    });
      // response[field] = sequence.next().value

    return response;
  }

  public static *stringSequence(prefix: string, initialValue = 0): Generator<string, string> {
    let i = initialValue - 1;
    while(true) { yield `${prefix} - ${++i}` }
  }

  public static getStringFields<T>(fields: StringFields<T>[], initialValue = -1): StringPartial<T> {
    const response: StringPartial<T> = {};

    fields.forEach(field => {
      const sequence = this.stringSequence(field as string, initialValue);
      response[field] = sequence.next().value as unknown as T[StringFields<T>];
    });

    return response;
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of the type assertion `as unknown as T[NumericFields<T>]` since all of the fields on `NumericPartial<T>` should be `number | undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914740/3821061),

> Use "for in" so that the compiler is able to infer that the variable "key" isn't just a string, but is actually a key in module's type.

So change your two `forEach` loops to:

```js
for (const field in fields) {
  response[field] = sequence.next().value;
}
```

and

```js
for (const field in fields) {
  const sequence = this.stringSequence(field, initialValue);
  response[field] = sequence.next().value;
}
```